# What can be the reason behind Microsoft graph API(/v1.0/me) returning NULL in "preferredLanguage" field in the profile object?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft365

My app on Microsoft Teams is using the consent flow to get the permissions from a user. Then with the access token returned by Microsoft, the app is trying to fetch the profile of the user using the `/v1.0/me` route. But for many users the `preferredLanguage` field in the profile object is `null`, only in some users the filed is returning a language. My app needs the preferred language of the user to show a translated version of the app.

#### I am requesting the following scopes from Microsoft.

1. User.Read
2. TeamsActivity.Send (not related to this issue)
3. offline_access (for refresh token)

#### Following is the code for the request for fetching the profile.

```js
const { data, status } = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,mail,displayName,givenName,businessPhones,preferredLanguage`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        ConsistencyLevel: 'eventual',
      },
});
```

#### Below are the screenshots of Microsoft 365 language settings and what the API is returning.

[image: Screenehot of Microsoft 365 language settings where the preferred language set as German]
[image: Screenshot of console log of the returned profile object where the preferred language is null]

Comment: I would suggest to check Azure AD portal: https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants/UserManagementMenuBlade/~/AllUsers/menuId/ try to add column PreferredLanguage and check if the language is set. If not, it can indicate some issue in Azure AD, not with the Graph API and permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with ***@user2250152***, while querying the user details if the **`preferredLanguage`** is displaying as `null` then the user might not have set the `preferredLanguage` in the Azure AD user details.

*Go to Azure Portal -> Users -> Select the user -> Overview -> Properties*

[image]

Initially I got the `preferredLanguage` as **null** while querying the user:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,mail,displayName,givenName,businessPhones,preferredLanguage
```

[image]

**Note** that: Some user properties/details cannot be updated directly from the Azure Portal, make use of Microsoft Graph API to update the **`preferredLanguage`** property.

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

{
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US"
}
```

[image]

After refreshing the user page, the **`preferredLanguage`** property is updated:

[image]

Now when I used the same query to fetch the user details, the **`preferredLanguage`** is displayed with the value:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,mail,displayName,givenName,businessPhones,preferredLanguage
```

[image]

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,mail,displayName,givenName,businessPhones,preferredLanguage)/$entity",
"id": "XXX",
"mail": "user@***.onmicrosoft.com",
"displayName": "user",
"givenName": null,
"businessPhones": [],
"preferredLanguage": "en-US"
}
```